# Swift. Best way to get Int from Int?

Tags: swift, option-type

I just started learning Swift and I'm still confused about Optionals. I was wondering, what's the best way of doing it or what way should I follow?

```
let arrayOptional : [Int?] = [25, 30, nil, 50, nil]
// Optional Binding
var sum = 0
for i in arrayOptional {
    if let temp = i {
        sum += temp
    }
}
sum = 0

// Forced Unwrapping
for i in arrayOptional {
    if i != nil {
        sum += i!
    }
}
sum = 0

// ?? operator
for i in arrayOptional {
    sum += i ?? 0
}
```

So are there any benefits of using one method over another?

Comment: Avoid forced unwrapping as much as possible, which of the other two is best depends on the situation and personal taste, in your specific example I would have used the last one but in general I prefer to use the first one.

Comment: Another option: `for case let i? in arrayOptional { sum += i }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unwrap it either using `if let` or `guard... else`.

```
//If let would be optimal for your example because you are not doing much after unwrapping 
for i in arrayOptional {
    if let temp = i {
        sum += temp
    }
}

// guard...else would be useful when you have a lot to do and you don't want to keep on nesting code inside {}
for i in arrayOptional {
    guard let temp = i else {
        continue
    }
    sum += temp
}
```

Force unwrapping (`!`) is only done when you want the app to crash or when you are certain that the optional will not contain `nil`. eg: Dequeuing a cell, UITextfield's and UITextView's `text` property is an optional but will never be `nil`.

The nil coalescing operator (`??`) provides a default value in case your optional turns out to `nil`. You use it while assigning an optional to a non-optional variable.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do, it's use `compactMap` function, so you will get the non-nil values from `arrayOptional` and then use `reduce` function to get result

```
sum = arrayOptional.compactMap{ $0 }.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate over the array twice, a single `reduce` can be used as my answer shows.

Comment: @DávidPásztor You are right but this is much easier to understand than your solution. However, it should probably include `.lazy` to avoid creating unnecessary arrays.

Comment: +1 (yeah; `.lazy` should probably be added, but it's not critical to understanding). This absolutely is the correct way to go about it in Swift. To @JoakimDanielson, I get that the question is asking whether let-binding, force-unwrapping, or nil-coalescing is better. The correct answer is "none of the above; use a higher-order function that does what you mean." Remove optionals. Sum. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a `reduce` to get the sum.

```
let sum = arrayOptional.reduce(into: 0, {$0 += $1 ?? 0})
```

In general, you should use optional binding (your first approach) or the nil coalescing operator (your last approach) for safely unwrapping optionals, nil check and then force unwrapping is not the recommended approach.

If you want to stick with a loop approach, you can make it simpler using pattern matching in the loop variable declaration (the body of the loop will only be executed for non-nil values in `arrayOptional`):

```
var sum = 0
for case let i? in arrayOptional {
    sum += i
}
```

Comment: @DávidPásztor the `reduce` approach is concise, but the addition will be executed for all elements, whether or not they are `nil`.

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes, but it won't effect the result, since the default value is set to `0` using the nil coalescing operator.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes it won't, I meant from an efficiency perspective

Comment: @Carpsen90 a single addition isn't really expensive computationally, so I wouldn't worry about that :)